# Unable to integrate pyest/pipenv project with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pytest, pipenv

1. I am trying to run my pytest frameowk project from Linux/Ubuntu Jenkin machine
2. I am able to clone code from Git repo using Jenkin job into /var/lib/bin/workspace folder
3. I am passing below two commands from Build step execute shell option

[image]

- First command `pip install pipenv` is running fine
- Second command `pipenv install requests` is NOT executing.
- Second command `pipenv install requests` is giving pipenv: not found **error** as below

[image]

Please let me know how to fix this

Basically i would like to run below commands from Jenkins and run my test case

pipenv install -r requirements.txt --dev file which contains below commands

- pip install pipenv
- pipenv install requests
- pipenv install pytest --dev
- pipenv install selenium --dev
- pipenv install pytest-html-reporter
- pipenv install vertica_python
- pipenv install psycopg2-binary
- pipenv install pytest-dependency==0.4.0

Comment: References https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CKTIkGxCNXU and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iotloCXtIzY

Answer (score -1):

This is solved from below vide

Make sure you have installed `sudo apt-get install python3.x-venv` library

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iotloCXtIzY

#!/bin/bash
echo " ### Create Pythin environment ### "
source scl_source enable rh-python36 # This step is NOT required if your python is already piinting to 3.*

VIRTUAL_ENV_NAME='virtual-environment'
python -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV_NAME

echo '### Activate Virtual Environment here ####'
source $VIRTUAL_ENV_NAME/bin/activate

echo '### Install requirements ###'

pipenv install -r requirements.txt --dev

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).